# Is there a way to add microsoft javascript for HDInsight to hadoop project?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

Just wonder if there is a way to add Microsoft's javascript for HDInsight to hadoop project?

Has Microsoft released their javascript solution as open source?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What javascript for HDInsight project are you referring to?

Our node.js SDK and command line tooling is available on Github (here's the CLI: https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli )

If that's not it, let me know!

--matt winkler, big data @ microsoft

Comment: I mean the javascript that replaces hive

Comment: http://www.networkworld.com/article/2161959/tech-primers/hadoop-on-windows-azure--hive-vs--javascript-for-processing-big-data.html

Comment: I think you are referring to what we used to call isotope.js, which was a javascript based way to author a job.  We experimented with that a few years back and decided not to proceed further with it. We considered open sourcing it, but it was a very partial implementation, so we didn't.

Comment: what is the recommanded language to execute hadoop job on HDInsight now? hive or javascript?

Comment: We see customers primarily using hive or pig, with a larger group using hive, because "it's just SQL."  Some customers use map/reduce directly, but that's primarily for parallel data munging that is going to reuse some existing code.  Personally, my favorite is [scalding](https://github.com/twitter/scalding), which feels very LINQ-like, just in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to write a solution for hadoop in pure Javascript, however Javascript can be used for writing Pig UDFs - http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/udf.html#js-udfs